# ssl certificate for subdomains on different servers

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I have a wildcard SSL from godaddy.

I had https://site1.mysite.com working good on a server.

I added DNS A record to route site2.mysite.com to IP of another server and got certificate from godaddy for the new config. Installed it on site2 server and https://site2.mysite.com works well.

Now I see that https://site1.mysite.com does not work. error Peer's Certificate has been revoked (Error code: sec_error_revoked_certificate).

What is the solution? Do I need to update  site1.mysite.com to the new certificate?

Answer (score 1):

If it is says the certificate is revoked, you either have the wrong certificate installed on site1.mysite.com or GoDaddy revoked it for some reason. Check that the right certificate is installed and then contact GoDaddy about why it is revoked.